# Как решить ошибку background.service_worker is currently disabled при загрузке временного расширения firefox?

Tags: firefox-extension

Я пытаюсь портировать [расширение из chrome](https://github.com/mrzlab630/chrome-extension-YoK) в firefox. При попытке его запустить как временное расширение выскакивает ошибка background.service_worker is currently disabled.
Покопавшись в интернете нашел [это](https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/develop/manifest-v3-migration-guide/), однако, я пытаюсь портировать это расширение по нужде и делаю это в первый раз, так что прошу помочь.